# All the datas are presenting in one row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, moya

as I'm new to swift I have a question about my code what exactly is its problem! I have table view which I'm supposed to put some data that I get it from API. I'm using alamofire and moya.

**I call this func in my vc to request to the web:**

```
class SmsPresenter
{
var view:SmsView?

func attachView(view: SmsView){
    self.view = view
}


func gettingEveyThing( aptId : String){
    ApiGenerator.request(targetApi: ApartemanService.getSmsInfo(aptId: aptId), responseModel: smsModelList.self, success: { (response) in
        self.view?.GettingEverthingSuccess(response: response.body)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
        self.view?.GettingEvethingFailed(errorMessage: "error")
    }
}
```

**This is my data model that I store them here:**

```
typealias smsModelList = [SmsModel]

struct SmsModel:Codable {
    var unitNo:Int?
    var unitPlaque:String?
    var billText:String?
    var contacts:[ContactsModel?]
    

}

struct ContactsModel:Codable
{
    var id :Int?
    var selected :Bool?
    var phoneNumber : String?
    var name : String?
    
}
```

**And this the func when I get 200 status code:**

```
func GettingEverthingSuccess(response: smsModelList?) {
    print("getting evething success")
    guard let response = response else {
        return
    }
    self.data = response

    self.tableview.reloadData()}
```

**My declartions:**

```
    var Presenter = SmsPresenter()
    var data : smsModelList?
    var Pphone : [String] = []
    var Nname : [String] = []
    var Iid : [Int] = []
```

**populating table:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell
    
    if let contacts = data?[indexPath.row].contacts
    {
        for eachmain in contacts
        {
            Pphone.append((eachmain?.phoneNumber)!)
            Nname.append((eachmain?.name)!)
            Iid.append((eachmain?.id)!)
        
        }
    }
 }
```

what exactly is wrong with my code :| ! when I run the code it puts the first number for first row then it put the second number for first ro again, though it should put the second number and other numbers for theire cell row.

[image: Photo]

***Api Response:***

```
[
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 9827,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "00987684044",
                "name": "OWNER"
            }
        ],
        "unitNo": 1,
        "unitPlaque": "Jack",
        "billText": "TEXTTEXT"
    },
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 10145,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "098887776655",
                "name": "mmm"
            }
        ],
        "unitNo": 2,
        "unitPlaque": "mm",
        "billText": "TEXTTEXT"
    }
]
```

[**crashLog**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsBpA.png)
[PPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vVuJ.png)

photo:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQL9M.jpg)

***the final answer for my was a combiniation of all the answers***

Comment: you are not serialise your data

Comment: `cellForRowAt` will call again and again because it's reusing cell so I don't think this approach will work to append data in `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: what do you mean? I get the data  and I can show it but in a wrong way

Comment: I just added a Photo

Comment: @DharmeshKheni what is your recommendation?

Comment: append your data to another arrays when you are receiving it from server.

Comment: how the data should display? What data should show in a cell?

Comment: Did you check "data" type. It should be an array. Otherwise data.count will not work.

Comment: @LalKrishna phone number and name from contact object should be shown in cell

Comment: @Arti as I just added the API response to my question, you see that my response is an array

Comment: var data : smsModelList? But this declaration does not seems to be an array. Try var data : [smsModelList]?

Comment: @Arti in the second part of my code you can see : typealias smsModelList = [SmsModel]

Comment: @AmirFT If your app is crashing at data.count, then only possible issue could be its not an array. So check when you are reloading the table at that time your data should be an array and has a proper count in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first crash you got because of force unwrapping `data` value.

you could return data count by using nil

```
data.count ?? 0
```

In this example, it seems you are iterating values inside the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. This isn't great idea because this method will be called a lot of times to display table. Dequeue & configure cell inside the cellForRow block and immediately return cell.

First populate data in format that you need.

```
func GettingEverthingSuccess(response: smsModelList?) {
     print("getting evething success")
     guard let response = response else { return }

     let contacts = response.flatMap { $0.contacts }
     for contact in contacts {
          Pphone.append(contact.phoneNumber!)
          Nname.append(contact.name!)
          Iid.append(contact.id!)
     }
     self.tableview.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let data = data else { return }
    return data.contacts.count
}

func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String {
     return data?[section].unitPlaque ?? ""
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell
    if let data = data, let contacts = data[indexPath.section].contacts, let contact = contacts[indexPath.row] {
       cell.phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumber!
       // ... more
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working if I only define one section . as I need the unitPlaque to be my section header, I'm getting a ridiculous issue!  I added the photo

Answer (score 1):

You're populating Table View wrong.
First you need to add number of sections in Table View:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

Then you need to add number of rows in section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Pphone.count
}
```

Then table view should be populated like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell

    cell.yourLabelInsideCell.text = Nname[indexPath.row]
    cell.otherLabelInsideCell.text = Pphone[indexPath.row]
    cell.idLabelInsideCell.text = Iid[indexPath.row]
    // etc
}
```

Also you need to map your response with your variables when receiving the request:

```
func GettingEverthingSuccess(response: smsModelList?) {
     print("getting evething success")
     guard let response = response else {
        return
     }
     self.data = response


     for contactData in data {
         if let contacts = contactData.contacts {
            for eachmain in contacts {
               Pphone.append(eachmain.phoneNumber!)
               Nname.append(eachmain.name!)
               Iid.append(eachmain.id!)
            }   
        }
    }
     self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

And don't forget that variables should start with small letter...

Comment: what does "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[ContactsModel?]'" mean?  I get this in func gettingeverthingseccess

Comment: I just edited my answer and that warning will be removed now

Comment: I unwrapped the optional because I was looping through data and there was no need for unwrapping again. And don't forget to mark it as accepted if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Try it again now, because I changed something in return for number of rows in section

Comment: I just added a photo to show you the error is still there

Comment: Try it now, because I added the possibility to return more than one section and now it should work as you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you added numberOfRowsInSection and what is the value you are passing in it?  As per your code, it would need to be like below code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
```

Comment: when I do this it crashes !! I have no idea why !

Comment: @LalKrishna Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100a662d0)

Comment: actually I need to return contact.count because each unitPlaque could take as many number as they want

Answer (score 0):

**use below code(ie. we have to check if data array has any values or not)**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if data != nil {
            return data.count
         }
   }
```

Comment: this prevented the app to crash and it works, but my data has 2 elements, but I need to return contact.count in all the elements , how should I go throw all of them

Answer (score 0):

To populate your data first of all return numberOfRowsInSection.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

Also as you said your app us crashing while returning data.count then make sure during table reload your variable "data" should be an array.